# How does one generate a single UIImage from an array of [UImage]s? Using Xcode9 and Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have a collection of UImages I have stored in an array var images = UIImage. I also have the corresponding relative position of x,y coordinates (0-100%) where they should be placed in the frame and I'd like to generate a single image from them. Anyone care to name methods or maybe a different type of image class that allows that relatively easy? Maybe there's some sort of CIFilter that does this?

Comment: Start with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and draw each image as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to draw a new image. Try something like this:

```
 func photoCollage(images: [UIImage], size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0)

    for (index, image) in images.enumerated() {
        image.scaled(imageSize).draw(at: CGPoint(
            x: //your position,
            y: // your position
        ))
    }

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```